# how to use a photoshop login in asp.net web page?

Tags: asp.net, photoshop

I have designed a log-in page in photoshop, saved the image in png format. but I dont know how to use this image in asp.net web page. Please help in this concern or show me the resource or the way I can design a good  log-in without compromising on polished look and functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a PSD Template into a CSS Template is not a easy task as it seems. Comprises may steps.

You have to following steps.

- Slice the images in your psd template.
- Export the images
- Try to minimize the use of photoshop generated slices as less as possible. You should try to recreate the effect using CSS the best you can.
- You can first try this into Table Structure, which is the default way Photoshop exports the slices and the HTML.
- Later on, create a table less layout. It should be pretty easy once you have created the table layout.

I am assuming, you know how to find the tutorials, regarding the steps I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cut the Photoshop image into several small images, and then use css to style it. I recommend you to learn  [html](http://www.w3schools.com/html/DEFAULT.asp) and [css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).

You can have a look at this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-builds/from-psd-to-html-building-a-set-of-website-designs-step-by-step/) on how to create a webpage from a Photoshop file.

Answer (score 0):

slice the `psd file` or copy merge ,and convert it into html page by using `<div>` and css. And name it as `indexloginpage.html` after converting `.html` what u have created the same in photoshop.

Rename the `indexloginpage.html` to `indexloginpage.aspx` and open this file in visual studio.
Apply code as per ur requirements.